# Google Colab: No option to restart and clear all outputs?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm experienced with Jupyter Notebook and am coming over to Google Colaboratory. I noticed that Colab does not have an option to restart the runtime and clear all the outputs; is that correct?

In **Jupyter Notebook**, the option is under `Kernel` --> `Restart & Clear Output`.

[image]

However, in **Google Colab**, there is no such option under the `Runtime` menu:

[image]

When I click on `Restart Runtime...`, it only shows the following:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To clear outputs, go to 'EDIT' and 'clear all outputs'.

If you want to reset all packages, data files etc. installed, you have got to the runtime as you mentioned.
Hopefully, it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why they put the clear outputs command under `Edit`, but whatever.

Answer (score 3):

2 step process in google colab

1. Edit>>Clear all outputs
2. Runtime>>Restart Runtime

Comment: But this doesn't seem to uninstall (possibly faulty or incompatible) packages installed before "Restart Runtime", so it's not a "Factory Reset". I think the only option is to save the notebook, end the Colab session and start a new Colab session. A "Factory Reset", as shown in the OP's screenshot, would be appreciated.